# Matching Values in a List to Column Names in a Data Frame to Update Values

Tags: r

I searched long and hard and could not find an answer to this, appreciate any help I can get.

I have two lists and a data frame.  The first list houses strings that are column names of the data frame:

```
> name_array[1:5]
[[1]]
[1] "40"

[[2]]
[1] "35" "50"

[[3]]
[1] "55"

[[4]]
[1] "35" "90"

[[5]]
[1] "30"
```

The second list houses values that correspond to the names in list 1:

```
> pct_array[1:5]
[[1]]
[1] 100

[[2]]
[1] 16.15629 83.84371

[[3]]
[1] 100

[[4]]
[1] 99.818551  0.181449

[[5]]
[1] 100
```

The data frame has a column for every possible name value in list 1, all the elements are set to 0:

```
> pct_rev_df[1:5,]
  15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 90
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I'm trying to write a code that will populate the dataframe with values from list number 2, when the column name matches the value in list #1.

In other words, the output should look like this:

```
> pct_rev_df[1:5,]
  15 20 25  30       35  40 45       50  55 60       90
1  0  0  0   0  0.00000 100  0  0.00000   0  0 0.000000
2  0  0  0   0 16.15629   0  0 83.84371   0  0 0.000000
3  0  0  0   0  0.00000   0  0  0.00000 100  0 0.000000
4  0  0  0   0 99.81855   0  0  0.00000   0  0 0.181449
5  0  0  0 100  0.00000   0  0  0.00000   0  0 0.000000
```

I have this working with a for loop, but the amount of data I'm putting through the script is too much for the for loop to handle:

```
for(i in 1:5){

pct_rev_df[i,match(name_array[[i]],names(pct_rev_df))] <- pct_array[[i]]

}
```

I have been scratching my head trying to figure out another solution (perhaps some form of apply?)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use row/column indexing.  Create the row index by replicating the sequence of rows based on the `lengths` of one of the `list` objects (assuming both `list` have the same structure)

```
rn <- rep(seq_len(nrow(pct_rev_df)), lengths(pct_array))
```

Similarly, create a column index by `match`ing the `unlist`ed 'name_array' with the `names` of 'pct_rev_df'

```
cn  <- match(unlist(name_array), names(pct_rev_df))
```

Extract the values of 'pct_rev' based on the index and assign it to values of 'pct_array' after converting to a `vector` (`unlist`)

```
pct_rev_df[cbind(rn, cn)] <- unlist(pct_array)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response.  Unfortunately in this case rn and cn are not the same length so it does not work.  When you unlist names_array you get more elements in the vector than the number of rows in the dataframe.  I really like the way you are going with this though, it's giving me some new ideas to try, thank you!